# How do I get event ID from Google Calendar API?

Tags: php, wordpress, google-calendar-api, event-id

Hey I'm using an API for first time, and I am confused about how to get event ID from Calendar API. Currently I'm using the sample quickstart.php file, and getting summary from this:

```
$results = $service->events->listEvents($calendarId, $optParams);
$events = $results->getItems();

if (empty($events)) {
    print "No upcoming events found.\n";
} else {
    print "Upcoming events:\n";
    foreach ($events as $event) {
        $start = $event->start->dateTime;
        if (empty($start)) {
            $start = $event->start->date;
        }
        printf("%s (%s)\n", $event->getSummary(), $start);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does `print_r($event);` return?

Comment: What have you tried to read it?

Comment: 'print_r($events)' returns all data in array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is so simple as mention above you can fetch id by `$event->ID` or you can use

`print_r($events)` to see the data.

Answer (score 2):

It's written in the [CalendarList Resource representation](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList#resource) of the documentation. `id` is part of the `calendarList Resource` object within the array of `items`. Within the foreach of `$events`

```
$event->id;
```

Comment: No problem. Just try debugging next time with var_dump or print_r